# A video I have won't load load in chrome. How can I fix it?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a webpage that includes a video within it. However, even though all of the file types (.mp4, .ogg, .avi) are supported in chrome, the video will not show.

I've already tried adding "preload="Metadata"" as described in a similar post, but it just loaded the thumbnail. once. I have also used Chrome's [inspect element] and my coding software's error finder, none of them have found any relevant errors.

```
<video  width="256px" preload="auto" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="Audio_Video/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" 
    preload="metadata">
    <source src="Audio_Video/Video.ogg" type="video/ogg" 
    preload="metadata">
    <source src="Audio_Video/Video.avi" type="video/avi" 
    preload="metadata">
</video>
```

I expect the video to load and play as it does on other browsers, but it in fact does not. All that appears is this: [A broken video that will not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDKlp.png)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Check your file path if it is breaking on the display. 
Here is a link to the MDN for more info. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: @HeroZero Everything that you suggested is there, but nothing works. Maybe it has something to do with my copy of Chrome?

Comment: I suspect this is not a browser issue but that could be checked by running your code in another browser to see if it worked there. If so this will narrow the scope.  I would probably start with checking the videos for playability straight from the desktop, look in the console for any errors, and clear browser cache and cookies.  If you see anything interesting update your question with the results.

Comment: I have checked the inspect element, and the software I use for coding does formatting checks, and neither of them found errors.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying, I was meaning to look for errors that are specific to the browser that would show up in the console.  We have established the code was correct.

Comment: Update: I just needed to re-render it in an H264 format.